# Can't build newest ckeditor 5 in production mode

Tags: ckeditor

When I build the ckeditor with ./

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development
```

Anything works fine, but when I try to build it with

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/ckeditorerror.js
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin/lib/translatesourceloader.js):
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:19) @
>   ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/utils/elementapimixin.js
>   6:0-72 33:13-26 @
>   ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js
>   @ ./app.js ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: keyword
>   (const)
>   [./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/log.js:46,0][bundle.js:160,0]

I can edit the ckeditor file and remove the const word, but then it just errors out on the next file which contains export const.

Her is the uglify-js version I use:

> ```
> "uglify-js": {
>   "version": "3.4.9",
>   "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-3.4.9.tgz",
>   "integrity": "sha512-8CJsbKOtEbnJsTyv6LE6m6ZKniqMiFWmm9sRbopbkGs3gMPPfd3Fh8iIA4Ykv5MgaTbqHr4BaoGLJLZNhsrW1Q==",
>   "dev": true,
>   "requires": {
>     "commander": "~2.17.1",
>     "source-map": "~0.6.1"
>   }
> },
> "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": {
>   "version": "2.0.1",
>   "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/-/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-2.0.1.tgz",
>   "integrity": "sha512-1HhCHkOB6wRCcv7htcz1QRPVbWPEY074RP9vzt/X0LF4xXm9l4YGd0qja7z88abDixQlnVwBjXsTBs+Xsn/eeQ==",
>   "dev": true,
>   "requires": {
>     "cacache": "^11.2.0",
>     "find-cache-dir": "^2.0.0",
>     "schema-utils": "^1.0.0",
>     "serialize-javascript": "^1.4.0",
>     "source-map": "^0.6.1",
>     "uglify-js": "^3.0.0",
>     "webpack-sources": "^1.1.0",
>     "worker-farm": "^1.5.2"
>   }
> },
> ```

-- Updated --
I kinda fixed it by removing  this from webpack.conf.js

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsWebpackPlugin( {
            sourceMap: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                output: {
                    // Preserve CKEditor 5 license comments.
                    comments: /^!/
                }
            }
        } )
    ]
},
```

Comment: im making a text color command for coloring text and im having the same error. Did you solve it?

Comment: I was unable to solve it,i remade it again and it worked great now, just with a bug but almost done.

Comment: @JrJimnz I kinda solved it. See update to question

Comment: Thank you, you should answer you own question and set it as the right answer to finalize the question as solved.

Comment: But I don't really think that disabling optimization is an answer. I would still like optimization to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too.  I switched to terser-webpack-plugin and can build successfully.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/362